# Matlab - How to generate LaTeX out of a transfer function?

Tags: matlab, latex

I have a transfer function as:

```
TF =

0.00995 z^7 - 0.02786 z^6 + 0.03611 z^5 - 0.0293 z^4 + 0.01565 z^3 - 0.005669 z^2 + 0.001274 z - 0.0001554
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     z^8 - 2.4 z^7 + 3.16 z^6 - 2.664 z^5 + 1.585 z^4 - 0.666 z^3 + 0.1975 z^2 - 0.0375 z + 0.003906
```

when I try:

```
[num,den] = tfdata(TF);
syms z
clipboard('copy', latex(poly2sym(cell2mat(num),z)/poly2sym(cell2mat(den),z)));
```

This is what I get which is not quite what I want :

[image]

How can I tweak my answer to look like the original transfer function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `evalc('TF')` is close to LaTeX format just form a string using `regexp`. First I make `TF`, trying to mimic the OPs value so that this is a MWE:

```
numIn=[0.00995  -0.02786 0.03611 -0.0293 0.01565 -0.005669 0.001274 -0.0001554];   
denIn=[1 -2.4 3.16 -2.664 1.585 -0.666 0.1975 -0.0375 0.003906];
TF=tf(numIn,denIn,1,'variable','z');
```

Then I find the numerator and denominator of the fraction by looking for more than 1 consecutive '-' and go back and forward to the newlines. Finally I form a LaTeX string.

```
fracparts=regexp(evalc('TF'),'([^\n]*)\n[ ]*-[-]+[ ]*\n([^\n]*)','tokens');
TFlatex=['T(z)=\frac{' fracparts{1}{1} '}{' fracparts{1}{2} '}'];
```

where `fracparts{1}{1}` is the numerator and `fracparts{1}{2}` is the denominator. The output is:

```
T(z)=\frac{  0.00995 z^7 - 0.02786 z^6 + 0.03611 z^5 - 0.0293 z^4 + 0.01565 z^3 - 0.005669 z^2 + 0.001274 z - 0.0001554}{       z^8 - 2.4 z^7 + 3.16 z^6 - 2.664 z^5 + 1.585 z^4 - 0.666 z^3 + 0.1975 z^2 - 0.0375 z + 0.003906}
```

which compiles in LaTeX with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$T(z)=\frac{  0.00995 z^7 - 0.02786 z^6 + 0.03611 z^5 - 0.0293 z^4 + 0.01565 z^3 - 0.005669 z^2 + 0.001274 z - 0.0001554}{       z^8 - 2.4 z^7 + 3.16 z^6 - 2.664 z^5 + 1.585 z^4 - 0.666 z^3 + 0.1975 z^2 - 0.0375 z + 0.003906}$
\end{document}
```

to give

[image]

For reference, I originally suggested using `vpa` (http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) to convert the rationals back into decimals, but this didn't work for the OP, either because we have different Matlab versions, or because my test `TF` was different.

Comment: `vpa(poly2sym(cell2mat(num),z),3)` in Matlab results in what I want but `clipboard('copy', latex(vpa(poly2sym(cell2mat(num),z),3)));` is same as before i.e. display coefficients as a long double

Comment: Are you sure? Look at `z` and put something else in the clipboard first. Also try `latex` but not `clipboard` to see the string produced. What version of Matlab are you using? It works for me with R2014b. Perhaps you could update your question with a working example, i.e. a simple (but sufficiently complicated) `TF` and the results you get?

Comment: POSITIVE. I use 2015a. Clipboard is clear before running the code. `latex` will result in same long format. `vpa` works absolutely fine as expected in matlab but as long as the `latex` is applied, the original values are used instead of truncated values.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I don't have 2015a, sorry. If you made a minimal example, we could see if it's due to the version. For interest, what do you get from `latex(vpa(poly2sym([1 1/5],z)))`? I get `'z + 0.2'`. Good luck.